# masstransit and multiple bus instances

Tags: azure, masstransit

According to MT documentation each bus instance should have a different queue name.

Am I right to assume that following is correct configuration?
[image: MT multiple buses]

What wires the WebApi and Backend queue together?

Consider even more advanced scenario

[image: MT combined with local transport]

When I design my backend pipeline to use message processing as well I can later slice it and let it use over the wire transport quite easilly. Question is, can I somehow configure MT so the Azure configured Bus relays the messages to the bus configured with local transport?

Comment: Is this question related to a specific tutorial / code sample? Without that example, or more context, this question isn't very clear. Also, given you called this a 'masstransit' example, I am assuming a *bus* is public-transport vehicle. Yet, you talk about a bus being something to publish and receive messages.

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: The use of an In-Memory transport is suspect, since it is not durable and message can be lost if the process exits. If that is acceptable, then you would use two IBus instances (a bus can only connect to a single transport type) and publish the events on the secondary one, while consuming the request from the queue2/asb source. The response could then be sent back to the requestor.

Comment: That is what I'm doing. But that means injecting second bus to the consumer which makes it kind of aware of the fact that there are two transports. I guess I'll have to live with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer this in the context of MassTransit v3, which supports both Azure Service Bus and RabbitMQ. If you are going to use Azure, I'd highly recommend v3 over the transport for v2.

First, about requests. They should be sent, not published. They are usually commands by nature, and not events. The only reason I see people publishing requests is that they don't have the endpoint address of the service. So knowing the endpoint helps, a lot.

Secondly, in your example, every WebAPI instance should have it's own queue to receive responses, since they are sent back to the requestor. With MT3, every `IBus` instance has a unique auto-delete queue that is setup for this very purpose, to handle responses from requests.

There is a sample, Sample-RequestResponse, in the MassTransit repository on GitHub, that shows how this is setup with RabbitMQ. It's about the same with Azure Service Bus.

The "fabric" that brings it all together is the virtual host (in RabbitMQ) or the namespace (in ASB). The connections between topics and queues determine how it all works together to form a logical *bus*.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I understand the part with azure namespace being the glue that wires it all together. I don't understand point about request response as that is what I'm doing in old fashioned http way. I've updated the question a bit to be more clear. If you could elaborate on the second picture as well it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is trying to us .NET Core + DI to register **multiple** busses:

- Do NOT use the build in `AddBus` call

  - No matter what you do it will never register more than one Bus due
  - This is because internally it calls [`TryAddSingleton`](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/428afa56e36c3657579343183235bdbd503e0831/src/Containers/MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration/Registration/ServiceCollectionConfigurator.cs#L41) call
  - `TryAddSingleton` only adds a new instance to the DI container if there is no instance registered for the interface yet
  - Note:

    - **No exception or error is thrown**

#### The solution we use

Since the various interfaces necessary are not generic:

- Created generic Wrappers around the built in interfaces
- Created an interfaces (used a generic parameters) that uniquely identify each RegisteredBus
- When a new Wrapper instance is created, we pass the instance of the built in interface into its constructor
- The Wrapper then holds the instance of the built in internal interface in a public property `Instance`
- Instead of injecting eg. `IBus`, we now inject `IBus<MyRegisteredBus>`

  - We then use the `Instance` property of the wrapper to get access to the built in interface instance and store it for later use (the wrapper plays no role after that)

We would love to not have to use some sort of wrapper with a weird `Instance` property, but short of the built in interface becoming generic or using something like `DynamicProxies` we could not come up with a more elegant solution.

Ideas / Feedback is very welcome.

#### Code

Generic `AddBus` call (otherwise 100% same signature as built in call):

```cs
        public static void AddBus<TBusType>(this IServiceCollection services, Func<IServiceProvider, IBusControl> busFactory)
            where TBusType : class, IBusType
        {
            IBusControl<TBusType> BusFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                return new BusControl<TBusType>(busFactory(serviceProvider));
            }

            services.AddSingleton<IBusControl<TBusType>>(BusFactory);
            services.AddSingleton<IBus<TBusType>>(provider => new Bus<TBusType>(provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl<TBusType>>().Instance));
        }
```

The various interfaces / classes we created to make this happen:

```cs
    // the only purpose of the interfaces derived from `IBusType` is to uniquely idnetify a registered Bus
    public interface IBusType { }
    public interface IHosted : IBusType { }
    public interface ILocal : IBusType { }

    public interface IBusTypeWrapper<TBusType, TInterface>
        where TBusType : IBusType
    {
        public TInterface Instance { get; }
    }

    public class BusTypeWrapper<TBusType, TInterface> : IBusTypeWrapper<TBusType, TInterface>
        where TBusType : IBusType
    {
        public TInterface Instance { get; }

        public BusTypeWrapper(TInterface instance)
        {
            Instance = instance;
        }
    }

    public interface IBusControl<T> : IBusTypeWrapper<T, IBusControl> where T : IBusType { }
    public class BusControl<T> : BusTypeWrapper<T, IBusControl>, IBusControl<T> where T : IBusType
    {
        public BusControl(IBusControl instance) : base(instance) { }
    }

    public interface IBus<T> : IBusTypeWrapper<T, IBus> where T : IBusType { }
    public class Bus<T> : BusTypeWrapper<T, IBus>, IBus<T> where T : IBusType
    {
        public Bus(IBus instance) : base(instance) { }
    }

    public interface ISendEndpointProvider<T> : IBusTypeWrapper<T, ISendEndpointProvider> where T : IBusType { }
    public class SendEndpointProvider<T> : BusTypeWrapper<T, ISendEndpointProvider>, ISendEndpointProvider<T> where T : IBusType
    {
        public SendEndpointProvider(ISendEndpointProvider instance) : base(instance) { }
    }
```

How to register generic `ISendEndpointProvider`:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider<ILocal>>(provider => new SendEndpointProvider<ILocal>(provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl<ILocal>>().Instance));
```

**UPDATE**

To an IHosted service for each Bus type:
- Create a generic `HostedService<BusType>` service
- Inject the `IBusControl<BusType>` in the constructor
- and use the injected instance to start stop the specific bus

Afterwards register a `IHostedService`for each bus type.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, HostedService<ILocal>>(); services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, HostedService<IHosted>>();`
```

Comment: Would be great to figure out a way to make this part of the framework...

Comment: Nice solution, it's working fine for producer, but how would you inject the IHostedService in this case?

Comment: I have added an update to outline how to handle registering an IHostedService per Bus. Also I wanne call out that @ChrisPatterson is currently working on a PR to incorporate this into the lib directly. Not sure when it will be released but shouldn't be too long based on how far he already got with the PR https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/pull/1864#issuecomment-626101132

Comment: It will be released with 6.3.0 in the next day or two. [Documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html)